# Evitar malas expresiones

Tags: c#, string, regex, entity-framework

mucho gusto, tengo un método que se le pasa una variable **Random** y regresa 4 caracteres aleatorios, el código funciona bien, pero tengo un problema, que la funcion puede regresar strings como

> S3X0, 53X0, P3N3, PUS...

que pueden ser consideradas como palabras obscena o groseras para algunos clientes.

se que puedo crear una lista en la que tenga esas palabras y si se encuentra ahi pues que vuelva a buscar, pero siento que no es la manera mas optima de realizar esa verificacion, me gustaria saber si alguien me podria dar una idea de hacerlo mejor, me refiero a que si el metodo regrese un string de ese tipo, pues que vuelva a buscar

```
private string generateRamdomCodes(Random random)
{
    string Code = String.Empty;
        
    string Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    int size = 4;

    char[] chars = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = Alphabet[StaticRandom.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
    }

    Code = new string(chars);
        
    return Code;
}
```

Comment: Y como sabe que el string es valido o no?

Comment: Igual siento que esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones... porque preguntas que conviene hacer.. no?

Comment: Si tienes q guardar las palabras en una lista, sino como el programa va a saber

Comment: Esto está graciosísimo. Sí sabes que tienes un posible máximo de 82251 combinaciones, si no te importa el orden y permites repeticiones? Tal vez las "malas expresiones" no sean tu mayor problema. Se te acabarán rapidísimo.

Comment: pues lo que es necesario es que no se tenga expresiones asi, no importa el orden, solo importa que no exista, PENE, P3N3, SEXO, S3XO, SEX0....

Comment: Usa la solución que te ofrecieron abajo o crea una lista con todas las palabras que quieres evitar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ese tipo de casos no creo que te quede otra mas que hardcodear una lista con todas las palabras que no quieres permitir y sus posibles derivados.

El tipo de palabras que has puesto (S3X0, P3N3 etc...) se conoce como `lenguaje 1337`.

Puedes crearte una funcion con el siguiente algoritmo.

```
bool isAllowed(List<string> forbbidenWords, string word)
{
   // Lo dejamos todo en minusculas para evitar casos sensitivos.
   word = word.ToLower();

   // Miramos si el string esta en la lista. (Si lo esta devuleves false).
   if (forbbidenWords.Contains(word))
      return false;

   // Remplaza los numeros (0, 1, 3, 5, 7) por (o, l, e, s, t)
   word = word.Replace('0', 'o')
              .Replace('1', 'l')
              .Replace('3', 'e')
              .Replace('5', 's')
              .Replace('7', 't');

   if (forbbidenWords.Contains(word))
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

Despues es solo crear tu lista de palabras prohibidas, y pasarle a la funcion dicha lista junto con la palabra generada, de la siguiente manera.

```
// Creas tu lista de palabras prohibidas (¡En minúscula!)
List<string> forbiddenWords = new List<string>() { "sexo", "pene" // ... };

// Comprobamos que funciona.
string word = "p3n3";

if (!isAllowed(forbiddenWords, word))
   Console.WriteLine("Palabra no permitida!!");
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, al final decidi almacenar el List en la base de datos para que el cliente pudiera guardar mas codigos que no quisiera que se repitieran y no tener que estar modificando mas el codigo, muchas gracias